# I need my created button to open close a content div in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, html, toggle

I have a div with content ie. short-code, images, links etc.

I need my switch to toggle the div container without jquery. I have spend days and would really appreciate some assistance.

I have included the switch code. On off the div must be display.style="none"

**html**

```
<img id="switch" onclick="changeImage()" src="http://designplatform.byethost15.com/on.png" width="60" height="150">
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function changeImage()
{
    element=document.getElementById('switch');
    if (element.src.match("off"))
    {
        element.src="http://designplatform.byethost15.com/on.png";
    }
    else
    {
        element.src="http://designplatform.byethost15.com/off.png";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you add your efforts so far to the question.  What you have posted is not really relevant.

Comment: I don't see any problem in code. what is the issue?

Comment: So what is your exact question? any errors? This code works perfectly. Please add more content and the part which is generating errors/issues to your question.

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this using jquery.

Add jquery to your html:
 
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Take out the `onclick=changeImage()` function from the `<img>` element, and add the following jquery(found in the first part of the snippett)  into your `<script>` tags on your html.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#switch").click(function () {
    if ( $("#switch").val()=="off")
{
$("#switch").attr("src","http://designplatform.byethost15.com/on.png");
  $("#switch").val("on");
}
else
{
  $("#switch").attr("src","http://designplatform.byethost15.com/off.png");
  $("#switch").val("off");
}
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="switch"    
src="http://designplatform.byethost15.com/on.png" width="60" height="150">
```

Comment: Although the code in your answer works, but actually it has nothing to do with the OP's question and what you are doing with `jQuery` OP is doing in `plain JavaScript`.

Comment: @EhsanT why did you down vote me? You your self even asked what his question was exactly. All i did was provide  a solution ("that works") what does it matter if it is jquery or javascript? But any way hope OP found what he was looking for.

Comment: Please don't get me wrong here. first of all I asked because the question is unclear, so I asked the OP to provide more info so we can help. second, although what you provided is **working**, but has nothing to do with the question and as I said before, the OP's code is exactly as your code and the OP's code is also **working**. you just applied `jQuery` to it. and maybe OP for some reason do not want or should not use `jQuery` in his code. That is the reason for the downvote. you just posted some answer that is not related to the question.

Comment: If you read the question again, OP has mentioned  _div must be display.style="none"_ but has not provided related code to this part, and that was the reason I commented and asked for more elaboration on the question